# Grpc proxy server for Google speech streaming api is not responding ( Grpc.Core.RpcException )

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, google-speech-api

We are trying to implement GRPC proxy server ( ASP.NET Core console app ) which will proxy incoming data to Google Speech streaming api. Code is pretty much the same as in [sample application](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize).

Proxy server purpose is multiple language recognition and api key protection.

For testing purpose I have created Windows forms application which sends available data ( audio chunks via DataAvailable handler ) to proxy server. Server starts recognizing transcripts, but after few recognitions ( approximately 5-10 ), it is not responding anymore. Actually every call from client to proxy server timeouts ( deadlines ).

On the client I am receiving next exception:

```
    Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=DeadlineExceeded, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
```

EDIT1 : server stops at this line. Client therefore gets deadline exception.
[image]

Comment: This is exactly the same problem we have.

Comment: Without more information, this is impossible to debug. I assume the problem is somewhere in your proxy (what is the speech api client running on the proxy doing while you receive the deadline?). Can you share code of your proxy or come up with a minimal reproduction? Are you sure you're not getting a deadlock for some reason, perhaps from mixing sync and async calls? (what are other threads doing?). What timeout are you using for what calls (I assume you are setting some when getting DeadlineExceeded)?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out, the problem was on server side with deadlocks because of asynchronous operations.

The solution is described [here](https://olitee.com/2015/01/c-async-await-common-deadlock-scenario/)

configureAwait(false) on asynchronous operations solved the problem then.

Comment: That didn't fix it for me. I'm getting the same error.