# Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll with Google Speech API

Tags: c#, google-api, windows-10, google-speech-api, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 with Google Speech API for a .NET Console project using C# with the following code:

```
class Program
{

    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> AsyncRecognizeGcsAsync()
    {
        var URI = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=...";

        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
        var longOperation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(new RecognitionConfig()
        {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Flac,
            SampleRateHertz = 44100,
            AudioChannelCount = 2,
            LanguageCode = "en",
        }, RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri(URI));
        longOperation = longOperation.PollUntilCompleted();
        var response = longOperation.Result;
        Console.WriteLine("response.Results.Count = " + response.Results.Count);
        foreach (var result in response.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Transcript: { alternative.Transcript}");
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start!");

        AsyncRecognizeGcsAsync();

    }

}
```

This is what I get in the Output Window:

```
Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
The program '[22028] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This is what I get in the Command Line Console:

```
Start!
**********

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 25260) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

How do I find out what the RpcException is? How do I go about fixing this?

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484096/grpc-proxy-server-for-google-speech-streaming-api-is-not-responding-grpc-core) on stack**overflow**, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, Did you happen t discover a solution to this?

Comment: @MikeB No. I found some things saying that Google Speech is incompatible with Xamarin. Basically Google doesn’t support it, if that information is correct.